# How do I block internet access within a defined time range?

Tags: osx, time-management, website-blocker

There are several questions out there regarding this issue, but none seem to address what I'm looking for.

- I think Leechblock is perfect for Firefox, but the problem is I'm on
  a Mac, and I also have access to Safari. Ideally, I'd like to delete
  Safari, but that's not possible unless I want to create potential
  issues within the OS. I'm also aware there are extensions such as
  WasteNoTime, but the problem with those is that they can be easily
  disabled through the Extensions tab in Safari's Preferences.
- I'm also aware that one can do this through a router, but I live on a
  campus dorm, so I don't have access to a router.
- Unplugging the ethernet cord is another possibility, but requires willpower and discipline (which I don't have).
- Programs such as MacFreedom and anti-social are other possibilities, but that can be disabled simply by restarting your computer.

Essentially I want to block off all internet access from in a defined time range, and be unable to change that option, just like one can do for Leechblock. Another option would be if I could block Safari completely without creating any unintended issues.

Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Aye, [SelfControl](https://selfcontrolapp.com/) does this. You can input specific domains to be black-/whitelisted or knock out connectivity across the board. The timer can't be reset by restarting your computer nor nullified by uninstalling. Great little application that does just what it claims and does it well.